# cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EBUSY)

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

I have an issue using the copy task in https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files
My task failed with an error cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EBUSY): ...

Looking up, I found out that somehow the file couldn't be overridden. When I delete that file and queue the build again, it succeeded.

Is there any permanent solution for this issue? I don't want to use the option "Clean target folder" in the copy task because in that folder there will be additional files that are not copied by the build task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the error message, the file is being used when the copy files task is running. You need to check which application is using it and make sure the application is closed when the task running. If the file is locked by any application, you may get "rm: could not remove the file (code EBUSY):..." error message even if you use the "Clean target folder" option.

Comment: The file is a dll. I guess no application is using it otherwise I wouldn't be able to delete it manually. Will opening the folder also cause the file to not be able to delete? I observed a couple time and found out that the build usually fails when I have the folder opened.

Comment: @LxL Trying using Process Explorer to check this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Thank Eddie, I'll keep that in mind and do further troubleshooting if I see the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

You run a web server reset command as workaround to pass through this problem if your application is running on web server for the open files to be released.